# Изменить цвет текста на #FF00CED1

Tags: c#

Как изменить цвет текста в консоли на #FF00CED1 (DarkTurquoise) ?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, [можно для конкретного фрагмента текста указать цвет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2743260/5752652).

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
Console.WriteLine("MyText");
```

Во-вторых [смотрите тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14792066/5752652). Это позволит вам указать цвета для всего консольного приложения.

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
Console.WriteLine("MyText");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В-третьих, вы можете указать свой кастомный цвет, задавая его составляющие RGB. Пример тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7937256/5752652 (чёт у меня не завёлся этот пример)

Также можете просто конвертировать ваш конкретный ([Color.DarkTurquoise](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.darkturquoise?view=netcore-2.1)) цвет из System.Drawing.Color к System.ConsoleColor воспользовавшись [таким кодом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29192463/5752652):

```
public static System.ConsoleColor FromColor(System.Drawing.Color c) {
    int index = (c.R > 128 | c.G > 128 | c.B > 128) ? 8 : 0; // Bright bit
    index |= (c.R > 64) ? 4 : 0;                             // Red bit
    index |= (c.G > 64) ? 2 : 0;                             // Green bit
    index |= (c.B > 64) ? 1 : 0;                             // Blue bit
    return (System.ConsoleColor)index;
}
```

Использование:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = FromColor(System.Drawing.Color.DarkTurquoise);
```